# How to troubleshoot "The statement failed to execute"

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

After losing a disc partition I have recovered our Sql Server database. The old database used merge replication to synchronise with mobile devices and I have been re-creating the replication. I can get a device to connect with the database but I get this error report:

> The SQL statement failed to execute. If this occurred while using
>   merge replication, this is an internal error. If this occurred while
>   using RDA, then the SQL statement is invalid either on the PULL
>   statement or on the SubmitSQL statement. [,,,SQL stateme 28560

How can I troubleshoot this further? I've tried running sql profiler on the main database to get the problem sql but I haven't managed to find any problem sql. What could be going on inside the merge replication that would cause this error message?

Comment: did u tried verbose logging ?

Comment: @KubaMiazek No. Where do I switch that on and view it?

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/07/13/using-verbose-history-agent-profile-while-troubleshooting-replication.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/03/04/kb-article-312292-how-to-enable-replication-agents-for-logging-to-output-files-in-sql-server.aspx